# Wordpress removes my menu items if above the Limit of 90 menu items -

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, submenu

I want to add more item in my menu

I've a menu that contains at least 90 item in wordPress menus (administration), I want to add more and I found that others are removed automatically.

Any solution?

Comment: usability wise a menu with 90 items seems excessive, do you have link to your site? - you could create another menu and store some items in that 'header' and 'footer' for example?

Comment: i need to add more, it works fine before until i upgrade wordpress to the last version, the website: http://assalamassociation.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most likelihood ( but not 100% ) , This is a PHP limit, not WP.

You can verify / configure it by looking at your php.ini.

Basically, the problem is `max_input_vars` variable in `php.ini`.

This [variable was introduced](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) in PHP version 5.3.9 and has the default value of 1000.

You should try to increase it to `1500` or even `2000`.

#### Further explanation : ( For those who want to understand more )

As you can see in the above php doc link, This is basically a limit applied to `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` superglobal separately.

Every time you click the `save menu` button in wordPress, you basically sending a lot of `POST` variables estimated by this formula :

```
"Total POST variables" = 11 * "number of menu items" + 9
```

So you can easily understand that when you add `90` menu items you are actually sending

```
( 11*90 )  + 9 = 999
```

that is too close to your default limit of `1000` and any further `POST` item will tip the limit ..

Similarly , When you add it via `POST Ajax` ( add menu by drag and drop ) the formula is a bit different - but the concept is the same ..

```
"Total POST variables" = 10 * "number of menu items" + 3
```

So just calculate your limit - and increase accordingly ( with ratio and a bit of safety margin.. just putting `10,0000` might work but it is not very logic .. )

Some further tech detail can be found [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134#comment:63) or [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/menu-item-limit-1)

#### PS :

A bit of googling will also find a [plugin to help you with a notification](https://github.com/sevenspark/menu-limit-detector) when you arrive to that limit.